# JavaScript equivalent of Perl's AUTOLOAD

Tags: javascript, perl, overloading

I think I might fail at Googling, and maybe this pattern just doesn't fit with the way JavaScript handles MRO, but I'm looking for an equivalent to Perl's AUTOLOAD method such that:

```
function car() {
  return {
    start: function() { alert('vrooom') },
    catchall: function() { alert('car does not do that'); }
  }
};

car().start(); //vrooom
car().growBeard(); //car does not do that
```

in Perl to quickly handle this situation I'd write:

```
sub AUTOLOAD { __PACKAGE__." doesn't do that" }
```

but the syntax to catch an undefined method in JavaScript eludes me.
Perhaps overloading .call or .apply or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to know if a method is defined you can do the following:

```
if(car().growBeard){
}
```

It sounds like what you are looking for is [`__noSuchMethod__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod), ***however it is only supported in mozilla***, and not part of the formal ECMAScript specifications.

```
function car() {
  return {
    start: function() { alert('vrooom'); },
    __noSuchMethod__ : function (){alert('no method');}
  };
}
```

Example of `__noSuchMethod__` on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Bb8Tx/1/), only works in a mozilla based browser.

Using simple exception handling you might be able to get your desired behavior:

```
try {
    car().start(); //vrooom
    car().growBeard();
}
catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to handle the situation where I don't know what method could be called. Ultimately I'd like to have the catchall method set properties based on the method's name. That is, car().color('red') might set car.color='red'

Comment: Thanks Mark, that would be exactly the ticket if it were standard. Hopefully there's another route possibly with exception handling which is compatible with most browsers.

Comment: @nebulous, I added an example using a simple `try{}catch{}`

Comment: Marked as answered because for the most part __noSuchMethod__ is what I was looking for. Unfortunately that try/catch example would require a try/catch around every call to car() rather than being definable within car(). I guess I'm just being too lazy and wanting things too dynamic. Perl spoiled me for other languages.

Answer (score 2):

The newish ES6 Proxy object will help: (sample code copied from [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Respond_to_an_unknown_method_call#JavaScript))

```
obj = new Proxy({}, {
  get: function(target, prop) {
    if (target[prop] === undefined)
      return function() {
        console.log('an otherwise undefined function!!');
      };
    else
      return target[prop];
  }
});
obj.f() // "an otherwise undefined function!!"
obj.l = function() { console.log(45); };
obj.l(); // "45"
```

Proxy objects are unshimmable. Browser support is good, but not perfect yet, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=proxy.